# Unclosed '(' does not match '}'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm trying to display an image on a laravel blade, but I'm having trouble displaying the $d["photo"] variable in the image address in the {{ url(' ') }}

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ulQ.png)[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zap6D.png)

Comment: Please post code and any error messages as text and not as images.

Comment: don't use double curly braces inside double curly braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on the template, change the second line for this:

```
  <img src='{{ url('img/foto-pengurus/' . $d['foto']) }}' class="img-fluid" alt=''>
```